# Prove that $f=0$ if $\varphi(y)=\int_\mathbb{R} |f(x+iy)|^2 d x$ is a bounded function.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Suppose that $f$ is an entire function of exponential type and
\begin{equation}
\varphi(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x+iy)|^2 d x
\end{equation} is a bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f=0$. The first theorem came to my mind is the Paley-Wiener Theorem which implies the existence of an $F \in L^2(0,\infty)$ such that
\begin{equation}
f(z)=\int_0^\infty F(t) e^{itz} dt
\end{equation} in the upper half plane. However, I can't go further. Please comment! Thanks!

Comment: Paley wiener implies that there is a ($L^2$) function of compact support in $[-A,A]$ for which the representation holds (integral being not $(0,\infty)$ but $[-A,A]$); use parseval to express $\phi$ and conclude

Comment: @ Conrad, I don't get your point. Do you mean that I can write $\varphi(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |F(t)|^2 dt$ for some $F \in L^2(-A,A)$?

Comment: $\varphi(y)=\int_{-A}^A e^{-2ty}|F(t)|^2 dt$ when $f(z)=\int_{-A}^A F(t) e^{itz} dt$; choosing $y \to -\infty$ shows that $F =0$ ae for $t \ge 0$ and $y \to \infty$ gives $F=0$ ae for $t \le 0$

Comment: I can see the key point now. Thanks very much!

Comment: happy to help, no problem!